# How to make hidden files visible in a folder in the finder?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder

I have created a file in the terminal using `touch <.filename>` with a **dot(.)** in the front and it is hidden, but I cannot see it in the finder. How can I enable **"show hidden files"**?

Comment: [Does command-shift-period not work?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402026/5472)

Comment: Let’s also recognize this thread - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340542/show-hidden-files-on-mac-os-x-mojave-using-terminal